# CASE statement ALIAS comparison

Tags: sql, oracle, case, alias

Here is my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT v.codi, m.nom, v.matricula, v.data_compra, v.color,
 v.combustible, v.asseguranca, 
(CASE WHEN lloguer.dataf IS NOT NULL THEN 'Si' ELSE 'Llogat'  END) AS Disponible 
FROM vehicle v 
INNER JOIN model m on model_codi=m.codi 
INNER JOIN lloguer on codi_vehicle=v.codi 
WHERE Disponible='Si';
```

What I'm trying to do it's to show only those rows that have the  "lloguer.dataf" is not NULL, but it doesn't alow me to use the "Disponible" alias to  do the last line comparison.

What can I do?

This is how the info is shown (with some more atribute) without the last line comparison.

[image]

Comment: use `WHERE lloguer.dataf IS NOT NULL` instead

Comment: Can't you simply write `where lloguer.dataf IS NOT NULL` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the alias doesnt exists yet. So you have to repeat the full code or create a subquery.

```
SELECT *
FROM ( .... ) YourQuery
WHERE Disponible='Si';
```

You can read more details here https://community.oracle.com/thread/1109532?tstart=0

Answer (score 1):

I'm a TSQL guy by nature, but can you do this?

```
Select distinct codi, nom,matricula, data_compra, colour, combustible, asseguranca from
(SELECT DISTINCT v.codi, m.nom, v.matricula, v.data_compra, v.color,
 v.combustible, v.asseguranca, 
(CASE WHEN lloguer.dataf IS NOT NULL THEN 'Si' ELSE 'Llogat'  END) AS Disponible 
FROM vehicle v 
INNER JOIN model m on model_codi=m.codi 
INNER JOIN lloguer on codi_vehicle=v.codi)
WHERE Disponible='Si';
```

As @JuanCarlosOropeza has stated, the alias doesn't exist until the data is initially fetched. This is why you would be able to use the alias in an `order by` clause without using a subquery, but not in the where clause as the data hasn't been fetched yet.

Comment: A litle explanation will be great.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza - I shall add some now.

Answer (score 1):

Remove your CASE WHEN from the SELECT block and replace your WHERE clause with:

```
WHERE lloguer.dataf IS NOT NULL
```